# How to serve PNG to HtmlImageLoadEventArgs callback as byte[]?

Tags: c#, png, html-rendering

I am using [HTML Renderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) to create a PDF. I implemented an image provider to server images (PNG). Its `HandleImageLoad` is properly called but the provided imgae is not shown in the PDF but something that looks like a clock(?) image.

This is the setup:

```
ImageProvider imgProvider = new ImageProvider();

PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(
    HTML, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4, 20, 
    null, null, imgProvider.HandleImageLoad);

public void HandleImageLoad(object sender, HtmlImageLoadEventArgs args)
{
      var img = LoadFromSource(args.Src);
        if(img == null)
        {
            args.Handled = false;
            args.Callback();
            Log.Error("Missing image: {0}", args.Src);
        }
        else
        {
            args.Handled = true;
            args.Callback(img.Data);
        }                                       
}
```

The variable `img` has stored a PNG as `byte[]` in the member named `Data`. Do I need any transformation or intermediary object to render the image propery as image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found it out. The image type must be of type `PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage`. The easiest way is to load the PNG fila as a `System.Drawing.Image`.

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream(img.Data))
{
    System.Drawing.Image sysImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem, false, true);
    var ximg = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(sysImg);
    args.Callback(ximg);
}
```